# Extract and display all 10 digit numbers comma separated from a text file in PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am looking for a a way to extract all 10 digit numbers comma separated from a text file which contains a mix of alphabets, digits and special character.

What i am able to do at the moment is use this code:

```
$texts  = "cache/en.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($texts);
$showtexts = explode(',', $contents);
$showtextsclean = preg_replace('/\d{10}/', '', $showtexts);

foreach($showtextsclean as $final) {
    echo $final;
}
```

what the code above does is do the opposite by displaying everything except the 10 digits numbers. What i actually want it extract all 10 digits and separate the by comma from example:

```
{"left-right-kato":1566025480,"ladies-night-sys-bjerre":1563248008,"catch-fire-bj-rnskov":1563179104,"jeg-dr-mte-om-en-r-d-lavth-ngende-sol-rasmus-walter":1562991777,"45-fahrenheit-girl-the-remixes-drew-sycamore":"not found","bebe-zk":1469386794,"ahora-rozenberg":1566345117,"precious-leave-me-on-the-floor-liss":1560827606}
```

So that I can echo it like this:

```
1566025480,1563248008,1563179104,1562991777,1469386794,1566345117,1560827606
```

Comment: Your example is JSON, `json_decode()` that string, iterate over the items and select the values that are 10 digits

Comment: That data looks to be valid JSON. Assuming that is no coincidence, you should _decode_ the JSON, not mess around with it with regular expressions.

Comment: @brombeer I know is JSON. I am using the file exactly the way it is somewhere but I need just the 10 digits else where

Comment: [this](https://3v4l.org/AJtO0) might help

Comment: or if there are mixed length digits: [`implode(",",preg_grep('~^\d{10}$~',json_decode($json_str,true)))`](https://tio.run/##PZHLbsJADEX3@Qo0QoJKsZSEkEcf6rZLPqAqGjJOMjCPyDOEFgS/TodUqre@vvfYHvrhfn9933xsomi@d9ZsnafZ22xxYQpbDyS73sOBe8ue03VRJNk6r5KYKS4kOjBT2/042O2RCCfRKguSpIpZw33TQysJQxvIuIMd/xRpWadJHrM9diAItEewGtAAgQDFR9@D6dAIBGcVEHf66ODElUeaDLK6TsuyjFm@hpb3hKZH6aGTpMD3CIRafgc@QXgKeA3X9gHHjPWz1h6NYDHb4Q7hfAh@eVGvqqKsAxDvLXEge0azQ@r@ll7l6zQNYQNhI20gUchHBB2gzRTXKmsJlHRuGkiqrCyS4rp4iaKR01Yc9bCUelBW4DIkx8Go23aEw3Jx@/oUlzS5zm@LeLq/wOYh@39G7OmIT6GCWRTd778)

Comment: @berend Thank you, that is exactly what i needed. You should post it as answer

Comment: @user3476168 glad it helped! Don't have the time now, but do go ahead and post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$showtextsclean = '{"left-right-kato":1566025480,"ladies-night-sys-bjerre":1563248008,"catch-fire-bj-rnskov":1563179104,"jeg-dr-mte-om-en-r-d-lavth-ngende-sol-rasmus-walter":1562991777,"45-fahrenheit-girl-the-remixes-drew-sycamore":"not found","bebe-zk":1469386794,"ahora-rozenberg":1566345117,"precious-leave-me-on-the-floor-liss":1560827606}';

$digig10 = '/\b(\d{10})\b/';
preg_match_all($digig10,$showtextsclean,$match);
print_r($match[1]);
?>
```

it replaces everything is not numbers that are greater or less than 10 digits

and trim comma from end and begin

gives this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1566025480
    [1] => 1563248008
    [2] => 1563179104
    [3] => 1562991777
    [4] => 1469386794
    [5] => 1566345117
    [6] => 1560827606
)
```

speed comparison of two solutions online PHP shells.

the speed of this [preg_match_all solution](https://tio.run/##XZHdbuIwEIXv8xTIQgKkjBpDSMh2d/sgZYWceBIb/BONzU9b9dlZk3Zv9vqcOfPNmVGN9/vPl1GN2Twof414i6EzKNzs12zxwQz2EUgPKsJJRM9@8G1VFettuStyZoTUGMBNcngL0B6RCCfTZp0sxS5nnYidgl4TJhnIhZO/fDl43fCizNkRB5AENiJ4C@iAQIIRl6jADegkQvAGSAR7DnAVJiJNAeum4XVd56zcQi8UoVOoIwyaDESFQGj1LfFJwmvC64T1DzjmfJz1/uwky1mLLcL7KeWVVbPZVXWTgITyJID8O7oWafg6elNuOU/LRsJO@0SSSrog2ATtpnW98Z7A6BCmgWK3rqui@lw8Z9lc6kEPvHh0@rRvl3v5wYvP1b59SmoKHA720dJBGLP8583/@0c@nzyr5@wi6CDPdlxqOxovcZnu@FZf@Z/VKnv5nd3vfwE)

```
Real time: 0.014 s
User time: 0.006 s
Sys. time: 0.009 s
CPU share: 99.45 %
Exit code: 0
```

is in comparison to the solution of [bubble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67466919/extract-and-display-all-10-digit-numbers-comma-separated-from-a-text-file-in-php/67467267#comment119248817_67466919)  speed of [json solution](https://tio.run/##PZHLbsJADEX3@Qo0QoJKsZSEkEcf6rZLPqAqGjJOMjCPyDOEFgS/TodUqre@vvfYHvrhfn9933xsomi@d9ZsnafZ22xxYQpbDyS73sOBe8ue03VRJNk6r5KYKS4kOjBT2/042O2RCCfRKguSpIpZw33TQysJQxvIuIMd/xRpWadJHrM9diAItEewGtAAgQDFR9@D6dAIBGcVEHf66ODElUeaDLK6TsuyjFm@hpb3hKZH6aGTpMD3CIRafgc@QXgKeA3X9gHHjPWz1h6NYDHb4Q7hfAh@eVGvqqKsAxDvLXEge0azQ@r@ll7l6zQNYQNhI20gUchHBB2gzRTXKmsJlHRuGkiqrCyS4rp4iaKR01Yc9bCUelBW4DIkx8Go23aEw3Jx@/oUlzS5zm@LeLq/wOYh@39G7OmIT6GCWRTd778)
nearly same:

```
Real time: 0.017 s
User time: 0.011 s
Sys. time: 0.006 s
CPU share: 98.71 %
Exit code: 0
```

sulutio [foreach](https://tio.run/##NZDRboIwFIbvfYqmMRETzgKKINvMHmWp9ECrpSWnBTeNz@4q23rZ852/X/9BDY/H@8eghsXy5J1lB7a6cYNtANKdCnAWwfHXfFeW2WZX7LOUGyE1erDz2H97OJ6QCGdou4lItk95I0KjoNWEcQxk/dlNv0Re1XlWpPyEHUiCPiC4HtACgQQjpqDAdmglgncGSPh@9HARJiDNAZu6zquqSnmxg1YoQqtQB@g0GQgKgbDXX9FPEl6iXiN695Tj1gXWutFKnvIjHhGu55hXlPV2X1Z1FBLKkQByV7RHpO7309til@fxsYGw0S6aGBQTQh@l7fxca5wjMNr7eSHbb6oyK@@rt8VSEMU6n61@SmycxGSuOGWBRlxHgNCPJjwrj3gbNUWjknlNeLachIkYuy1YPLpNfCCDNvm/PxxYnq3Zf8jL4W@DvbBVGvPui0nQpxz7IaFAuk/@yPQ5Xq/fHo8f) of [berend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67466919/extract-and-display-all-10-digit-numbers-comma-separated-from-a-text-file-in-php/67467267#comment119248778_67466919)

```
Real time: 0.016 s
User time: 0.006 s
Sys. time: 0.008 s
CPU share: 87.91 %
Exit code: 0
```

Comment: This does not separate the with commas

Comment: It also captures other numbers that are greater or less than 10 digits